# How to install and/or run Universal Media Server on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, server, ffmpeg, mediaserver

I have installed [UMS](http://www.universalmediaserver.com/) onto my Ubuntu box according to the [manual here](http://www.slsmk.com/how-to-install-universal-media-server-ums-on-ubuntu-in-headless-mode/). All commands worked fine except two:

1) I was unable to install `ffmpeg` package which is absent in this version of Ubuntu. I have installed `libav-tools` instead and was expecting to fix possible errors later.

2) I was unable to run

```
update-rc.d /etc/init.d/UMS defaults
```

as written, so I ran

```
update-rc.d UMS defaults
```

and it apparently worked.

Finally I have service, but nothing happens if I run or stop it. If I run it many times (without stopping) or if I stop it many times (without running), I get no any error message.

The is no `debug.log` file appearing in `UMS` directory.

I can't open page http://localhost:5001 or http://localhost:9001 (unreached error occurs).

What to do? How to check the installation?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably running ums with root privileges, which is what the documentation states against. You need to create a new account on your install or use your own profile. This is also the reason why debug.log is not generated.

Steps to follow : 
login as root or > sudo -i , once you are in your own account command prompt.
enter password

```
> update-rc.d -f UMS remove
> exit
> sudo chown YOURUSER:YOURGROUP -R /opt/ums
> chmod u=rwx,grx,o= -R /opt/ums
```

Now, if you look in the opt/ums directory you will find a folder named linux. This actually contains the versions of ffmpeg and tsMuxeR we need. so change these paths in UMS.conf

```
> cd /opt/ums
> nano UMS.conf
```

Search for section "# Non-GUI Options"
then start with changing paths as follows :

```
mencoder_path = /usr/bin/mencoder
ffmpeg_path =/opt/ums/linux/ffmpeg
mplayer_path = /usr/bin/mplayer
......

if you need to check the paths use : whereis mencoder
```

Once done, if there are any packages missing like mencoder, manually install them from their respective websites.
for remaning just use this with root login:

```
apt-get install mediainfo flac
```

This should install all required codecs. Update paths accordingly in UMS.conf file. Then run UMS.sh with your own profile as
./UMS.sh
If there are any errors post them here.